# Build Failure Error while doing maven install in command prompt

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn

I am getting the below error while building the code in command prompt using maven install

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.overstock.mojo:svn-info-plugin:1.0:svn-info (default) on project SupplierOasis-automation: error in calling

[svnversion, .]: Cannot run program "svnversion" (in directory "D:\pxworkspace\SupplierOasis-auto
mation"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

Please help me out in this regard.

Comment: Do you have the Subversion command line client installed? Is it in your PATH?

Comment: This doesnt have any specific command line.I have this SVN installed from the below link http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/update-site/

Comment: Your `install` goal is looking for a program called `svnversion` which is from the Subversion command line. You need to install a Subversion command line client. You can use the one from [SlikSVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download), [Wandisco](http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/download) (look below the SmartSVN Client). You'll need to put the SVN `bin` directory in your PATH environment variable. I don't know why `install` is doing this because normally `install` doesn't care about your source repository.

Comment: Downloaded theSVN client from SlikSVN and the configured the SVN bin path in the Environment variable.Up on running the mvn install command  I have received the below error and the BUILD was failed.Please find the below error[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.11:test (default-test) on project SupplierOasis-automation: Error occured in starting fork, check output in log -> [Help 1]

Comment: Can you append to your answer and put the error there? It's hard to see what's going on. This way, you can provide a longer, more detailed explanation.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail. What is the type of project you have? How is your settings.xml set? The `install` goal usually just copies the built jar into the `.m2/repository` directory in your _HONE_ directory. The purpose is to allow you to build the jar for project "A" that project "B" needs w/o having to install that jar into the Maven repo that other users share. For example, I change a method in Jar "A" that I am using in Project "B".

Answer (score 0):

try on command line

**svn upgrade**

then again run the build. It should fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar issues on a Mac if you recently upgraded XCode and have not yet accepted the license.  Open XCode and accept the license.